# Spring Active directory test case with username in UPN format username@domain

Tags: spring, spring-security, active-directory, spring-ldap

With my spring active directory test case, if use username in UPN format `username@domain` it is failing and giving following exception, but same is working with `CN=username,OU=Users,DC=internal,DC=test,DC=com`

```
Caused by: javax.naming.InvalidNameException: [LDAP: error code 34 - Unable to parse bind DN 'usename@internal.test.com':  Unable to parse string 'usename@internal.test.com' as a DN because it does not have an equal sign after RDN attribute 'usename@internal.test.com'.]
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:3099)
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2890)
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(LdapCtx.java:2804)
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.<init>(LdapCtx.java:320)
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURL(LdapCtxFactory.java:192)
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURLs(LdapCtxFactory.java:210)
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance(LdapCtxFactory.java:153)
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getInitialContext(LdapCtxFactory.java:83)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:730)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:305)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:236)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext.<init>(InitialLdapContext.java:154)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource.getDirContextInstance(LdapContextSource.java:42)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.createContext(AbstractContextSource.java:343)
```